# How can I get the current domain in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I want to get the current domain so if the page is http://www.domain.com/page.asp I need `www.domain.com`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")'
```

To be complete, one of my functions:

```
  function PageUrl
     dim sPort
     sPort = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")
     if sPort = "80" then
        sPort = ""
     else
        sPort = ":" & sPort
     end if

     PageUrl = "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & sPort & _
                           Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?" & _
                           Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
  end function
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the Request Servervariables (server_name?)

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: <%= Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") %>

Answer (score 0):

Put this before the end of your function to remove the `?` when there is no querystring element, as a random `?` at the end may not be what you want:

```
If right(PageUrl,1)="?" then PageUrl = left(PageUrl,len(PageUrl)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
for each x in Request.ServerVariables
response.write(x&"="&Request.ServerVariables(x)&"<br>")
next
%>
```

This will gives you results like this with all Request.ServerVariables

```
REMOTE_ADDR = 40.20.170.160
REMOTE_HOST = 40.20.170.160
REMOTE_USER = 
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
SCRIPT_NAME = /xyz/get.asp
SERVER_NAME = www.xyz.com
SERVER_PORT = 80
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Explanation added :)